# (Google Cloud) Recreate instance VM maintaining the internal IP of the original machine

Tags: google-cloud-platform

How can I recreate a virtual machine of GCP, maintaining the internal IP of the original machine?

I want to recreate a virtual machine due to an installation error and it is necessary to maintain the private IP (It only has one internal IP).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reserve the internal IP address and assign that reserved address when creating the Compute Engine instance.

The IP address is reserved and be used for any one instance. When you delete the instance, the IP address remains reserved.

[Reserve a static internal IP address](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-internal-ip-address)

[Create a VM instance with a reserved internal IPv4 or IPv6 address](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-internal-ip-address#create_a_vm_instance_with_a_specific_internal_ip_address)